# How to automatically include labels and data in my scatterplot function in R?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot

I'm going back to practicing making functions at the moment and I came up with this super basic scatterplot that I'm still trying to customize a bit:

```
#### Quick Scatter ####
library(tidyverse)
quick.scatter <- function(data,
                          x.var,
                          y.var){
  d <- data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=x.var,
               y=y.var))+
    geom_point(alpha=.4)+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm",
                color="red")+
    labs(title = "Scatterplot of Data",
         x="Predictor",
         y="Outcome Variable")+
    theme_bw()
  return(d)
}
```

If you plug in the `iris` dataset for example, it should give you a quick scatter:

```
quick.scatter(iris,
              x.var = iris$Sepal.Width,
              y.var = iris$Sepal.Length)
```

[image]

There are a few things I want to refine with this. First, I would like to get rid of the "data" argument here so I can just plug in my values like:

```
quick.scatter(df$x,df$y)
```

Second, I want to know if there is an easy way to automatically name the x and y axis based off the variables included. So if I used the code above, I would like it to automatically have the following labels:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for your use-case?

```r
library(tidyverse)

quick.scatter <- function(x, y){
  x_name <- gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(x)))
  y_name <- gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(y)))
  data <- data.frame(x_name = x,
                     y_name = y)
  d <- data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=x_name,
               y=y_name))+
    geom_point(alpha=.4)+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm",
                color="red")+
    labs(title = "Scatterplot of Data",
         x=x_name,
         y=y_name)+
    theme_bw()
  print(d)
}

quick.scatter(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Sepal.Length)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for. Do you mind explaining whats going on with the x.name and y.name parts? I have no idea what any of that does, but the rest of the code makes sense.

Comment: It's a bit complicated, but basically it's capturing the function argument (the 'word' "iris$Petal.Length") rather than the values it represents (the 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, etc). More details here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html . The `gsub()` part is selecting everything after the "$" sign (i.e. the "Petal.Length" part)

Comment: You're very welcome; thanks for including all the required details in your question :)